# Android: not able to get the color with using the ColourPicker but can get color after get the focus on that view

Tags: android, android-layout, colors, android-canvas, color-picker

In My Paint application i am going to pick the colour from the colourpicker.

MyApp is like that: [This link](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html)

Now i am using [this class](http://code.google.com/p/android-ac/source/browse/trunk/src/de/rothbayern/android/ac/keithwiley/UberColorPickerDialog.java?spec=svn23&r=23) to pick the colour.

the code i use to pick the colour is:

```
public void pickColour(){
    takePhotoFromCamera = false;
    takePhotoFromGallery = false;
    new UberColorPickerDialog(TWSBIDrawMainActivity.this, this, canvasColor, true).show(); // generats error here
    myView.getVisibility();
}
```

the Override method fot that picker is:

```
@Override
public void colorChanged(int color) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TWSBIDrawMainActivity.canvasColor = color;
    float hsv[] = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(TWSBIDrawMainActivity.canvasColor, hsv);
}
```

And i am drawing that colour in MyView class with code:

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        //canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        // set the Canvas Color
        canvas.drawColor(canvasColor);
 }
```

Now while i select colourfrom picker then it is selected but when i press on accept it is not going to effect on that view but while i touch on that view then it takes effect.

Instead of that i want is that the colour should be get effect when i press accept from the picker.

Please help me in this.
Thanks.

Edited:

Please see this Screen Shot:
[image]

Here after opening the dialog if i press the accept button then the colour should be take effect on the white background. but instead of that right now if i press accept button and then if i touch on the white background then only the color take effect. So what should i have to do ?

Hope you got my point.
I realy need help of this issue.
please help me. .
Thanks.

Comment: Should i have to get the focus on the view where i am going to draw the color in fuction ?

Comment: can you explain what exactly you want...do you already have a line drawn whose color you want to change? or what?

Comment: @havexz : In that Link application, colour picker is for the mPaint colour but instead of that i am giong to use that picker to set the background color of the canvas. But it is going to be effect after the dialog is close and if i touch on the view.

Comment: Supose if i change the color of the background with this picker then it is going to be effect after i touch to that view.

Comment: so you want the color to take effect right when you select and not after you touch the view? Can you provide a screen shot?

Comment: @havexz : i have updated the question with the screen shot so please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

The soln looks like you have to call the invalidate on the view after color is selected.

try `myView.invalidate()` in `colorChanged` like

```
@Override
public void colorChanged(int color) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TWSBIDrawMainActivity.canvasColor = color;
    float hsv[] = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(TWSBIDrawMainActivity.canvasColor, hsv);
    myView.invalidate();
}
```

Here is more help on [view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have done like it but still not getting the effect.

Answer (score 0):

You change in the MyView class in the OnDraw function like this.

@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

```
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    int colorPicked = MainActivity.selectedColor;

    paint1 = createPen(colorPicked);
     for (Path p : paths){       
         canvas.drawPath(p, paint1);
         paint1.setColor(colorPicked);
         }

    }

private Paint createPen(int color) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    paint1 = new Paint();
    paint1.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint1.setDither(true);
    paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint1.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint1.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint1.setStrokeWidth(3);
    return paint1;
}
```